# Why doesn't my compiler generate N number of random numbers when I use 10^6 but is alright with 10^5?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int r = atoi(argv[1]);
unsigned int N = atoi(argv[2]);
int n[N];
int i = 0;
int rando = 0;
int average = 0;
int stddev = 0;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
rando = rand () % r;
n[i] = rando;
average += rando;
stddev += pow(rando, 2);
}

for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
printf("Array Element %d:[%d]  \n", i, n[i]);
printf("The average of all numbers is %d\n", average / N);
printf("The standard deviation of all numbers is %lf\n", sqrt(stddev/N));
}
```

I'm generating random integers such that I enter random numbers between 1 and r-1 N times.

So, on my command line I type ./myprogram 10 1000000 and the compiler just sort of spits out nothing.

If I were to say, type in ./myprogram 10 100000, it would work just fine, albeit a little slow.

However, with another 0 it doesn't want to cooperate, why is this?

Comment: can you try after dynamically allocating the space for the array n? (see malloc()) Here it seems the array ends up in the stack, when I would have expected the code to not even compile... And i should better be unsigned, but you're far from the maximum values, so it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Yes, giant local arrays are often a problem.  (There are many duplicate questions about this.) Do try `int *n = malloc(N * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: So I allocated the memory, checked my task manager and I ended up hogging more memory than Chrome!! LOL.

Comment: @MATT_BOOTY : Well `n` requires ~4Mb of space - that is not an issue with malloc, that is what your code is asking for.  It is simply that the heap can satisfy that request, while that stack cannot, because it is fixed to typically 1Mb (Windows).  With the stack and the heap allocation, I'd expect  <5Mb for teh process. The default stack of a Windows thread for example is 1Mb, so the 400K you allocated for `n` is fine (though I'll advised - VLAs are generally a bad idea, but here you allow unconstrained size).